# why Maxmimum likelihood estimation is used for multilevel analysis?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, multilevel-analysis

In multi-level modeling, why not use OLS?
are there any specific reasons behind that?

And why do people recommend using restricted maximum likelihood rather than maximum likelihood in multi-model data?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It would be helpful to give references for where you have seen the recommendation to use restricted maximum likelihood. Are you, for instance, in a situation where there are more features than observations?

Comment: I saw it on a certain web page. the logic was that, in almost every hierarchical (nested) data, level 2 observation (i.e., school) is outnumbered by level 1 observations (i.e., students). That's why restricted maximum likelihood is more suitable rather than ML. But I don't understand that logic.